# Bug: Tor Browser 11.0.9 - 12.0.6 tries to connect to Mozilla services on Startup

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, connection

On a fresh, new installation of Tor Browser v11.0.9, I noticed that even though *Show alerts about passwords for breached websites* in **Tor Browser Preferences** > ***Privacy & Security*** is disabled by default:

[image: Screenshot of Tor Browser Preferences]

Tor Browser still tries to connect to `firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com` on startup:

[image: Screenshot Tor Browser Firewall Alert]

According to Firefox own Help Docs [How to stop Firefox from making automatic connections](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections) and [Turn off website breach alerts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-password-manager-alerts-breached-websites), this shouldn't be happening.

---

This bug seems to persist in **Tor Browser 12.0.4** too, and now it also seems to phone Securedrop.org on startup:

[image: Tor Browser 12.0.4 Phoning Mozilla and Securedrop]

---

Bug still persists in **Tor Browser 12.0.6**:

[image: Screenshot Tor Browser 12.0.6 Firewall Alert]

Comment: This might be the same as https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40788.

Comment: @Steve Yes, you may be right - it does seem to be an old regression that hasn't been fixed. I wonder why?

Comment: @Steve Issue persists with Tor Browser v11.0.11 too ...

Comment: @Steve Could you post your comment as an answer with some more detail? It seems this is related to the question and as far as I see it the bug is closed and the bugfix will be shipped with the next alpha release.

Comment: @JensKubieziel Do you have more details when the bugfix will be shipped? The latest version (12.0.6) still has this bug and still tries to call Mozilla and Securedrop.